# How to merge item stacks?

Tags: fire-emblem-three-houses

I have a couple of stacks of 01/03 and 02/03 vulneraries and I recall in previous games it was possible to merge these to leave just one 03/03 stack to save inventory space.

Is this still possible in this entry?

Comment: I don't *think* you can stack them in this game, for whatever reason... I have also not found a way to in playing or researching it. But that seems like such a minor (yet very annoying) oversight that I'll hold out hope that I'm wrong and simply leave a comment... :)

Answer (score 4):

Items in this game are in random arrangement (in the order you acquire them perhaps) and **cannot be sorted or stacked**.

Don't bother organizing your inventories. Just store the items (vulneraries). Trick: give your characters weapons, then give them back their vulnerary.

It really doesn't look like vulneraries can restack. No matter what I try. It hasn't been a mechanic in other games either. *(Edit: it was definitely a thing in Shadow Dragon and Awakening — reports scohe001)*

Trick #2: Equip/unequip stuff on a character to get items in at least some semblance of order. (Armor first, then weapons, or best>good>okay>bad, or what ever organizational system you like.)

But, good news; they take up almost no space whatsoever. All stack into one item slot in the end, so in total there will be just 4 rusted weapon stacks. Hoard one of each weapon type as they can be useful later.

Don't bother to sell them, you only get ~1g. Waste of time for not much space freed at all.

Comment: `It hasn't been a mechanic in other games either.` IIRC, it was definitely a thing in Shadow Dragon and Awakening. It even worked with weapons too!!

Comment: Items are not in a random arrangement, most definitely not the consumables, as they are neatly stacked. The same item (i.e. same item type + durability) stacks, but the inventory does show **equipped** items separately. So if I have 10 concoctions in the convoy and 3 units with a concoction, I will see 4 lines (e.g. Convoy x10, Byleth x1, Edelgard x1, Hubert x1)